# My MacBook Pro cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I last had my computer connected 3 days ago to a wireless network (the one I am still on with other computers). AirPort says it's connected and has a strong green light (full bars in wifi) but when I open System Preferences, the 902.1X: WPA: says FreeWiFi_Secure and the button says Connect, so I press that and under that it says "Authentication server is not responding" and has the waiting signal (spinning flower thing).

The wifi works as I am on it on my phone and no one else is having trouble in the house.

Can someone please help this damsel in distress!

Comment: What are your DNS settings?

Comment: If you hold the option key and select the Wireless icon in the menu bar, is there a **Open Wireless Diagnostics** and/or **Open Network Diagnostics** tool that you could run to narrow down where the failure is. If not, you might want to edit in your OS X software version so someone could point you to an appropriate troubleshooting guide for your OS.

Comment: I don't know what the DNS settings are.